# How can I retrieve data (JSON) in React from the beginning and then export it as I wish in any other file of my app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

I need to have a file, let's say `data.js`. This file is going to fetch data with async/await `fetch()` from a MongoDB database. I would like to somehow **pause** the React execution until I have retrieved the data. Then start the React and export data to any file I wish.
I am asking because it is like with `async/await` my app is executing in a "parallel" way
so it seems impossible to *assign a promise result in a variable* in some point of my app like :

```
let data = {};
get_data().then((result) => (data = result));
```

It just keeps the `data` variable undefined.

Answer (score -1):

There are various method by which you can do that.

- First i guess let variable will only be in functional scope and can't get
  its value until return.
- Second You can declare any setState in your code and use it by exporting
  that component anywhere you want.
- Third is debouncing method in which you can make your function wait and then use that data in your UI.

if the result is coming undefiend then idk what you asking for.
i wish this helps you.

```js
For debouncing 

const debounce = (func) => {
    let timer;
    return function (...args) {
      const context = this;
      if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(() => {
        timer = null;
        func.apply(context, args);
      }, 500);
    };
  };

  const handleChange = (value) => {
    fetch(`https://demo.dataverse.org/api/search?q=${value}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => setSuggestions(json.data.items));
  };

  const optimizedFn = useCallback(debounce(handleChange), []);
```

Comment: The code snippet doesn't work and returns a syntax error.

Comment: I have cheked the snippets very well , its 100% working code. You just need use them properly.
https://javascript.plainenglish.io/implementing-debouncing-in-react-f3316ef344f5

Comment: When you press the "Run code snippet" button in your answer, it shows "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'debouncing'". If the code is not runnable in a Stack snippet, please post it as regular code block. Only runnable code should be posted as snippet

Comment: i have not gave you running code , you need to write by your own same logic , even i provided you refrence. See above there is link.